# Hiding a part of actual url in cpanel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

say, I have 3 php files inside 'test' folder (eg. example1.php, example2.php, example3.php,) inside cpanel. If a user types test/example1.php, is there any way to only display only  **test/** inside browser url box using .htaccess file?

Comment: Possibly. What should show in the browser though? The contents of `example1.php` or something else?

Comment: I suppose you could use [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method), ie `history.replaceState({}, document.title, './')` in each of those pages. It's all client-side so not really a full solution

Comment: the contents of example1.php @Phil

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the URL server-side is with a redirect. The problem there is that once you redirect to `test/`, how would you know which file to display?

One client-side solution would be to include a JS snippet or file on each page that replaces the current history entry with that of the parent directory. For example

```
<script>
history.replaceState(null, document.title, './')
</script>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method

Keep in mind, that if the user does request `test/`, there's no way to decide which file to render so Apache will just choose the configured directory index. See https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings